# Loop through XML document using XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I have the below XML, and I am trying to write values to a CSV file. I am however not sure how to proceed further, with everything I've tried throwing errors. The below returns:"Expression must evaluate to a node-set". Any assistance is appreciated.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
   <Body>
  <RESULT>
     <SUCCESS>TRUE</SUCCESS>
     <Mailing>
        <MailingId>9285984</MailingId>
        <ReportId>362040252</ReportId>
        <ScheduledTS>2014-08-22 11:44:33.0</ScheduledTS>
        <MailingName>305_ENDS</MailingName>
     </Mailing>
     <Mailing>
        <MailingId>9278770</MailingId>
        <ReportId>361956135</ReportId>
        <ScheduledTS>2014-08-22 09:15:00.0</ScheduledTS>
        <MailingName>141_TSI</MailingName>
        <Visibility>Shared</Visibility>
     </Mailing>
     <Mailing>
        <MailingId>9286460</MailingId>
        <ReportId>362043622</ReportId>
        <ScheduledTS>2014-08-22 12:57:30.0</ScheduledTS>
        <MailingName>301_BRANDREP</MailingName>
     </Mailing>
  </RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

C#:

```
xpathDoc = HttpHelper.HttpStream(xmlReq, sessionid);

XPathNavigator nav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();

XPathNodeIterator xmlIterator = nav.Select("/Envelope/Body/RESULT/");

var csv = new StringBuilder();

filePath = "C:\Campaigns.csv";

foreach (XPathNavigator node in xmlIterator)
{

string MailingId = node.SelectSingleNode("MailingId").Value;
string ReportId = node.SelectSingleNode("ReportId").Value;
string ScheduledTS = node.SelectSingleNode("ScheduledTS").Value;
string MailingName = node.SelectSingleNode("MailingName").Value;

string newLine = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", MailingId, ReportId, ScheduledTS, MailingName, Environment.NewLine);
csv.Append(newLine);

}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, csv.ToString());
```

Comment: `with everything I've tried throwing errors` <-- Which errors? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try following approach:

```
foreach (XPathNavigator node in nav.Select("/Envelope/Body/RESULT/Mailing"))
{
    string MailingId = node.SelectSingleNode("./MailingId").Value;
    // and so on
```

Note: it should be exactly `Mailing` not `RESULT` as in your query, and should **not** ends with `/`

Comment: Thanks. It works! btw, what is the difference between "./MailingId" and using "MailingId"?

Comment: @stats101 In fact, there is no difference in this particular case. Prefix `./` means "select starting relatively from current node" in xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Change `XPathNavigator node in nav.Select("/Envelope/Body/RESULT/")` to `XPathNavigator node in nav.Select("/Envelope/Body/RESULT/Mailing")` and then use e.g. `string MailingId = node.SelectSingleNode("MailingId").Value;`.